Databricks: Dynamic SQL | How to union all the queries from a list of queries?
I am developing an idea following the logic of dynamic SQL in databricks. Purpose is to save manual work.
I have a table which stores all the parameters that I will use in the dynamic SQL query. Then I use concatenation to generate SQL query using these parameters.
The table is called 'DQ_FOM_SOURCE_SETUP', it contains these columns and rows:

The dynamic SQL query I wrote is:
-- 2. Dynamic SQL query for Source 2
SELECT 
'SELECT ' || 
TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_GROUP_2) || ', ' ||
"'" || TRIM(SOURCE_COLUMN_2) || "' AS Metric, " ||
"'" || TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_2) || "' AS TABLE_2_Name, " ||
'SUM(' || TRIM(SOURCE_COLUMN_2) || ') AS SUM_Value_2 ' ||
'FROM ' || TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_2) || ' ' ||
'GROUP BY ' || TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_GROUP_2) AS sql_statement
FROM DQ_FOM_SOURCE_SETUP;

The result looks like this:

Now, the next step is to union all the queries in the result. I tried multiple ways, for example, I tried:
SELECT CONCAT(dynamic_sql, ' UNION ALL ') AS full_sql
FROM (
SELECT 
    'SELECT ' || 
    TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_GROUP_2) || ' AS ' || TRIM(SOURCE_COLUMN_ALIAS_2) || ', ' ||
    'SUM(' || TRIM(SOURCE_COLUMN_2) || ') AS SUM_' || TRIM(SOURCE_COLUMN_2) || ' FROM ' ||
    TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_2) || ' GROUP BY ' || TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_GROUP_2) AS dynamic_sql
FROM DQ_FOM_SOURCE_SETUP
) AS subquery;

But what it returns is still a list of queries instead of a big query which unions all the sub queries.
Do you know how to union all the queries in the result table? I want to find an efficient way to union them because there may be hundreds of rows in the DQ_FOM_SOURCE_SETUP table in the future, I cannot mannually write the union statements, that's why I want to use dynamic SQL. Thank you so much for your help.


You probably seek something like a string aggregate function: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/databricks-sql-string-agg/td-p/17432 No comment on whether all this is a good idea though.

If you are ok, You can achieve this using a combination of Pyspark and databricks SQL.
If you want to just get the actual query, you can iterate through the rows and keep appending the statements along with the union keyword.
However, my answer will not only give you the actual final query but it will also execute the query and give you the result.
Write a pyspark function where you pass your sql statement and execute in the function using df = spark.sql(<sql_statement>, then store the df as a tempoary view.
Keeping passing the view back for each statement and let the function do the union.
Now outside the function you can do a select from the temp view and you have your data.
First I'm creating my Sample input tables
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table1 (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Jane'),
(3, 'Bob');

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sqlstmts (
    sqlstmt VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO sqlstmts VALUES
('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = 1'),
('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = 2');

Next I execute my function. After fetching my SQL statements, I convert it to a pandas dataframe to iterate through it.
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

#Create an empty temp view with matching schema as required output table
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), StructField("name", StringType(), False)
])
tempdf = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
tempdf.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")

def union_func(sql_stmt,view_name):
    df = spark.sql(sql_stmt)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view2")
    uniondf = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM temp_view2 UNION SELECT * FROM {view_name}")
    uniondf.createOrReplaceTempView(view_name)

# Get your SQL statements
spark_df = spark.sql("SELECT * from sqlstmts;")
pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
final_union_stmt = ""

print("The SQL Statements are as follows---")
print("-------------------------------------------------")
for index, row in pandas_df.iterrows():
    if final_union_stmt != "":
        final_union_stmt = final_union_stmt + " union "
    print(row['sqlstmt'])
    union_func(row['sqlstmt'],"temp_view")
    final_union_stmt = final_union_stmt + row['sqlstmt']

print(f"Final Union statement is :{final_union_stmt};")

And finally I fetch my results from my output view
%sql
SELECT * FROM temp_view;

Another way to approach this is to form the actual sql statement using the loop and then execute it in 1 go. You can remove the execute of sql statements if you just need the sql union statement.

To concatenate all the sql_statement field values with the UNION ALL operator, you can use the collect_set and array_join functions. Below is the databricks SQL code.
Code:
SELECT array_join(collect_set(sql_statement),' union all ') AS full_sql
FROM (
    SELECT 
        'SELECT ' || 
        TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_GROUP_2) || ', ' ||
        "'" || TRIM(SOURCE_COLUMN_2) || "' AS COLUMNNAME, " ||
        "'" || TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_2) || "' AS TABLE_2_Name, " ||
        'SUM(' || TRIM(SOURCE_COLUMN_2) || ') AS SUM_Value_2 ' ||
        'FROM ' || TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_2) || ' ' ||
        'GROUP BY ' || TRIM(SOURCE_TABLE_GROUP_2) AS sql_statement
    FROM <TABLENAME>
) AS subquery;

